# Cannot implicitly convert type void to string

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> itemsNames = new List<string>();
        List<decimal> itemsPrices = new List<decimal>();

        itemsNames.Add("Bread");
        itemsNames.Add("Milk");
        itemsNames.Add("Juice");
        itemsNames.Add("Chocolate");
        itemsNames.Add("Cheese");
        itemsNames.Add("Ham");
        itemsNames.Add("Chicken");

        itemsPrices.Add(2.50M);
        itemsPrices.Add(3.00M);
        itemsPrices.Add(4.50M);
        itemsPrices.Add(1.50M);
        itemsPrices.Add(2.50M);
        itemsPrices.Add(3.50M);
        itemsPrices.Add(13.50M);

        string result = CombineTheLists(itemsNames, itemsPrices);

        Console.WriteLine("\r\nPress enter to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void CombineTheLists(List<string> itemNames, List<decimal> itemPrices)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < itemNames.Count; i++)
        {
            string result = "";
            string names = itemNames[i];
            decimal prices = itemPrices[i];
            Console.WriteLine($"The {names} costs ${prices}");
        }
    }
```

I've been trying to figure the proper way to make the function call to the method I created in the code provided. When I attempt to make the function call it just shows the cannot convert void to string error and I know it's because the method I created is and must be void. Is there a work around my issue?

Comment: you need to change return type of your function to string

Comment: Use proper return type!

Comment: Void means nothing is returned, you need to return a List<string> from CombineTheLists()

Comment: I know that the function is void is meant to be that way. I am trying to make the function call while storing the values inside a variable so that I can output to the console window.

Comment: "I am trying to make the function call while storing the values inside a variable" - storing *which* values? What do you expect the value of `result` to be, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your function to return something, it should not be `void`. If you don't want it to return something, `string result =` is not necessary. You have to decide what you really need. (**EDIT:** *Looks like you already did, and other answers covered this very well*). Also instead of holding those two lists, you should create a `class` or `struct` to your items:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price{ get; set; }

    public Item(string name, decimal price)
    {
        Name = name;
        Price = price;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

    items.Add(new Item("Bread", 2.50M));
    items.Add(new Item("Milk", 3.00M));
    items.Add(new Item("Juice", 4.50M));
    items.Add(new Item("Chocolate", 1.50M));
    items.Add(new Item("Cheese", 2.50M));
    items.Add(new Item("Ham", 3.50M));
    items.Add(new Item("Chicken", 13.50M));

    string result = PrintList(itemsNames, itemsPrices);

    Console.WriteLine("\r\nPress enter to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static string PrintList(List<Item> items)
{
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        string names = items[i].Name;
        decimal prices = items[i].Price;
        sb.AppendLine($"The {names} costs ${prices}");
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

This will make your life much easier.

**EDIT2:** Other ways to loop through the list:

**foreach:**

```
foreach(Item i in items)
{
    string name = i.Name;
    decimal price = i.Price;
}
```

**while:**

```
int i = 0;
while(i < items.Count) 
{
    string name = items[i].Name;
    decimal price = items[i].Price;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Got it!, thanks.
Do you think that's the proper way of looping through two lists?

Comment: When you have more than one variable referring to the same object (in your case, the items), this is the proper way to handle it. This is what object oriented programming is all about. :) Take a look at the basics of it, it's an important requisite for c# programming.

Comment: How could I loop through the two list with a while loop and foreach (out of curiosity)?

Comment: I'll add it to the answer

Comment: Thanks. I understand now.

Comment: Nice! Glad to help! I think you should keep the other answer as the chosen one. It's more related to the original question than mine.

Answer (score 1):

`CombineTheLists` does not return anything, but you're trying to assign it to a string:

```
string result = CombineTheLists(itemsNames, itemsPrices);
```

Change it to return a string (and, obviously return it, instead of using `Console.WriteLine`) or dont try to capture the return if you did want to just write to the console.

```
CombineTheLists(itemsNames, itemsPrices);
```

---

As an alternative if you were tryingg to build a string inside the method, and return it you could use a `StringBuilder`:

```
public static string CombineTheLists(List<string> itemNames, List<decimal> itemPrices)
{
    var sb = new StringBuidler();
    for (int i = 0; i < itemNames.Count; i++)
    {
        string result = "";
        string names = itemNames[i];
        decimal prices = itemPrices[i];
        sb.AppendLine($"The {names} costs ${prices}");
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Note that I changed the return type to `string` - you can then call it as your original code

```
string result = CombineTheLists(itemsNames, itemsPrices);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call it with this line:

```
string result = CombineTheLists(itemsNames, itemsPrices);
```

you are taking the result of the CombineTheLists method and trying to convert its result to a `string`, storing the result in a variable called `result`.

You are not actually using the `result` variable, so you needn't create it in the first place.

More importantly, the return type of `CombineTheLists` is explicitly void:

```
public static void CombineTheLists(List<string> itemNames, List<decimal> itemPrices)
```

and as the method does not include a `return` statement, it does not return a string either.

To fix this you simply need to do this instead:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> itemsNames = new List<string>();
    List<decimal> itemsPrices = new List<decimal>();

    itemsNames.Add("Bread");
    itemsNames.Add("Milk");
    itemsNames.Add("Juice");
    itemsNames.Add("Chocolate");
    itemsNames.Add("Cheese");
    itemsNames.Add("Ham");
    itemsNames.Add("Chicken");

    itemsPrices.Add(2.50M);
    itemsPrices.Add(3.00M);
    itemsPrices.Add(4.50M);
    itemsPrices.Add(1.50M);
    itemsPrices.Add(2.50M);
    itemsPrices.Add(3.50M);
    itemsPrices.Add(13.50M);

    string result = CombineTheLists(itemsNames, itemsPrices);
    Console.Write(result);

    Console.WriteLine("\r\nPress enter to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static string CombineTheLists(List<string> itemNames, List<decimal> itemPrices)
{
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < itemNames.Count; i++)
    {
        string names = itemNames[i];
        decimal prices = itemPrices[i];
        stringBuilder.AppendLine($"The {names} costs ${prices}");
    }
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: well, I was hoping to output the results of the function after with a Console.WriteLine();

Comment: @SaroCode see my answer for that

Comment: @MattStyles is that the proper way of looping through two lists at the same time? I tried with a while loop and foreach couldn't come up with it.

Comment: @SaroCode I think it's ok, as it allowed you to use the same index (`i`) in both Lists. Really though, you could use something like a List of KeyValuePairs for this:  `var items = new List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>>();` then `items.Add("Bread", "2.50M");`

Then you only have to loop through one list, with a `foreach (var item in items) Console.WriteLine($"The {item.Key} costs ${item.Value}");`

Comment: you could remove `string result = "";` inside the `CombineTheLists` method

Answer (score 0):

Change the `return type` of your `function`

```
public static string CombineTheLists(List<string> itemNames, List<decimal> itemPrices)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < itemNames.Count; i++)
        {
            string result = "";
            string names = itemNames[i];
            decimal prices = itemPrices[i];
            Console.WriteLine($"The {names} costs ${prices}");
        }
      return "somestring from CombineTheLists function";
    }
```

or

Don't expect from the `function` it will `return` `string` and make a simple `call` to the `function`.